# Where is the forest field in openlayers plugin on Qgis?

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I am mapping out a region in my community and there is a vast forest area (I identified it from the openstreetmaponline map) and I will like to extract the shapefile polygon vector, but I don't know the 'key' value on the openlayers plugin on Qgis 2.14

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the "key",you can go to this site, https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/318610815 and click on the map for show the key.

[image]

this example the 'Key value' is building.

And after go to Qgis and dowload data with QOSM plugin.

[image]

Comment: Yes that s what I just did (image 1) to figureout the area was a forest, but using the plugin, I tried the following keys: natural, landuse, (and some other) but their values hadn't forest among. I gues I might just vectorise it, I know it will definitely be tidious

Answer (score 0):

The QGIS Openlayers plugin can only show tiles from the OpenStreetMap server. If you want to see key-value attributes from the OpenStreetMap database, you have to use their website, the QGIS QuickOSM plugin or an OpenStreetMap editor like JOSM.

Using http://www.openstreetmap.org, zoom to the border of the forest, then click on the levels icon (the 4th on the right side panel), and activate the map data checkbox (the last one).

Now you can click on the forest border line, to get the way id in the left side panel. If you have hit an overlaying border of an adjacent landuse (like farmland), you might have to try other border segments.

If you don't see tags for `landuse=wood` or `forest` at the top, scroll down to see if the way is part of a relation that describes the forest. You would have to download that with Overpass API to get the complete forest.

QuickOSM does not mention it, but you can build Overpass queries using the id directly:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#Query_by_element_id

The correct syntax would be for a way:

```
way(23649584);>;
out;
```

and for a relation:

```
relation(6135889);>>;
out;
```